# Hello Everyone i have one issues on go green wordpress premium theme

Tags: wordpress, editor

I am new in WordPress and when I install fresh Wordpress and buy one premium Theme **go green** when I try to save my content on this theme editore I got internal server error can anyone help here

please check the screenshot here http://prntscr.com/ozjp6l

Comment: Please, describe more your question and clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there maybe a lot of reason but first can you please check is there any updates available in your WordPress and then please check?

You need to upgrade it to 5.6 or newer then 5.6 and then it will work.

Comment: Hey buddy thanks but as i check on my WordPress backend there is no update available because i recently bought this so i think all plugins and theme both are updated by the way thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you please checked the PHP version?

Comment: as i check with my cpanel PHP version is 5.5 is there any issues with PHP version ?

Comment: Can you please upgrade it to 5.6 or newer then 5.6 and then check

Comment: ok let me update my PHP version

Comment: Thanks @pixlogix its working now

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general HTTP status code. It means something is wrong with the site’s server. Don't get me wrong, the problem could be from your Wordpress installation or site server. Either ways, it has impacted the site server.

Since there are many factors (e.g .htaccess, plugin-theme compatibility issues, etc.) that could be responsible, it is best to talk to your Host first.

Comment: Thank you @mcmemdal001 update PHP version and it's working fine for me thanks for your replay